# Passing same Object through Activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Im currently trying to pass the ***same*** Object trough an activity. What I mean with that is, that I **don't** want to create or clone the Object with the same attributes/values . (I don't want to create a new Object in the Heap, I just want to use the already existing Object from the passing Activity).

Is that even possible ?

I don't want to work with static objects either. I already tried the Parceable Interface (which is creating a new Object and not useable in my case)

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("items",allItems);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("selected_items", selectedItems);
```

Comment: If all activities belong to the same app in the same process it can be done e.g. with a static member variable which holds the object (doesn't mean that it is recommended to do that at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can only do so by using static objects(which you shouldn't) or by storing the object somewhere that is scoped at the application level and both activities can have access to (e.g. a singleton).

Writing to parcel/serializing and sending it through the intent bundle will create a new instance which is not what you want.